# Passing named function as a callback in Typescript

Tags: typescript, callback

I've been googling for a while now and can't seem to find a final answer. Say that I have a function that returns a promise :

```
function doStuff(argument) {
    // ... some code here
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Is it possible to do this :

```
let deferred = Http.get(url)
    .then(doStuff);
```

Instead of this :

```
let deferred = Http.get(url)
    .then(result => doStuff(result));
```

Comment: it possible but you will lose the clojure context if you need any. In other words **this** will change.

Comment: you mean if I use `this` inside the declaration of function `doStuff()` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine. What problems are you facing?

Comment: Okay thanks, well tbh I didn't try, I had doubts about the return value so I googled it and couldn't find any occurence or piece of code showing this so I thought, might as well ask here for the next people who search for this.

Comment: It'll all work. It's basically the same. But like Ki Jéy said, the context will be different. But as long as you don't use `this` inside `doStuff` you're good. Also, another way of doing it is using `doStuff.bind(this)` instead of `result => doStuff(result)`.